# Why isn't this split in javascript working?

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe I drank too much tonight, but why isn't this split on the question mark working?

```
url = "report/app?start_date=&end_date=&industries"
url.split('/\?/');
```

Comment: Why a regex, `url.split('?');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're splitting using the **String** whose content is `/\?/`. Use a regex literal instead, to split on using the regex.

```
url.split(/\?/);
```

Howevery, you could simply do `url.split('?')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes around the regex  delimiter `/`.

```
url.split(/\?/);
```